# How can i append a child to a div that has a random number as an id?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

READ THE EDIT AT THE BOTTOM! :)

I am making a little website where the user can fill in multiple text boxes, and when they come back later, their text boxes come back. (Pretty much a terrible helpdesk system using localstorage).

I have three fields the user can fill out, then when the fields are submitted they should appear below, in a div. Currently i am only able to get the first field to be shown, as i append it to a static div, but i want to append the rest of the fields to the first one. This wouldnt be too hard, but i cant seem to append a child to a div that doesnt have a set ID (without somehow hardcoding it).

I have tried things like

```
divAId +  i.appendChild(divB)
```

And

```
var divAIdNumber = divAId + i;
divAIdNumber.appendChild(divB);
```

, but nothing seems to work.

Here is the code in question:

```
gradStorages = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('gradStorages'));
var iFeil = 0;
function feilDivCreate(){
    const divF = document.createElement("div");
    divF.className = "feilDiv";
    divF.id = "feilDivId" + iFeil;
    listIdIncrement();
    divF.appendChild(document.createTextNode(set1));
    textContainer2.appendChild(divF);
    iFeil += 1;
}

var iOffer = 0;
var feilIdNumber = "feilId";
function offerDivCreate(){
    const divO = document.createElement("div");
    divO.className = "offerDiv";
    divO.id = "offerDivId" + iOffer;
    listIdIncrement();
    divO.appendChild(document.createTextNode(set1));
    feilIdNumber + iOffer.appendChild(divO);
    iOffer += 1;
    console.log(feilIdNumber + "TATATATAT");
}


var set1 = "set1 Not Defined";
var set2 = "set2 Not Defined";
var set3 = "set3 Not Defined";


function extract(){
    for(let i = 0; i < feilStorages.length; i++){
        set1 = feilStorages[i];
        set2 = offerStorages[i];
        set3 = gradStorages[i];
        feilDivCreate();    
        offerDivCreate();
        gradDivCreate(); // same as offerDiv
    }
}
```

(can add more, or make a jsfiddle if needed.)

I need a way to append `offerDiv` to `feilDiv`, but its not so simple because `feilDiv`'s id is `feilDivId + i` where `i` goes up by one for each new `feildiv` added.

Any tips for how i can achieve this?

**EDIT**: *Here is a simplified version, showing all the code necessary to understand what im trying to do. https://codepen.io/kossi1337/pen/xxKPRvv
Might be easier to just make a new question with all the new code, but im not too sure if that allowed.. Let me know if i have to change anything about my question :)*

Comment: You should create a code snippet here. It's kindof hard to understand the problem if we don't have an example.

Comment: Can you post enough of your code, as an “*[mcve]*”, that would allow us to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Not to be a dick or anything, but the only thing i need to know is how to append a child to a div who's id is "idName + i" (where "i" goes up by one for every new div).. It can be reproduced, but i dont really see the point... Is there one?

Comment: Yes, it lets us see what you’re working with, what you might be assuming, what/where you might wish to append and create a simple demo in our answers to provide a specific example relevant to your problem. As well as providing a clear relationship between your question and our answers that might benefit future visitors as well as yourself. It’s *also* a requirement of the site to have such code in your question, plus there’s the fact that offered to do just that in your question.

Comment: My bad. I recreated the whole thing to make it a bit simpler, and i made a codePen : https://codepen.io/kossi1337/pen/xxKPRvv

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
var divAIdNumber = divAId + i;
divAIdNumber.appendChild(divB);
```

It seems like you are trying to append an element to the Integer value you just created by adding i to some number. You need to grab the parent node, either via document.querySelector or using jQuery, then append to the parent. The browser has no idea what to do when you try to append markup to a number. It expects a DOM location that it will be appended to.

It should be like this:

```
var divAIdNumber = divAId + i;
var html = "<div class='" + divAIdNumber + "'> Content here </div>";
var element = document.querySelector(".my-element");
element.appendChild(html);
```

Comment: Something like `container2.appendchild(myDiv)` works. But i want to append myDiv to container0, then the next myDiv should be appended to container1, then container2, etc etc. I have updated my question with a codepen so its easier to understand :)